# Three statements regarding the sign of derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $f$ is a derivable function defined over $[a,b]$. Then the following hold :

1. For a point $c$ in $[a,b]$, if $f'(c)>0$ then $f$ is increasing at $c$.
2. Moreover, if the derived function $f'$ is continuous at $c$, then there is a neighborhood of $c$ where $f$ is strictly increasing.
3. If $f'(x)≥0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$.

Are my conclusions correct?

Comment: Point 3 needs to be strictly greater than, if $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ it's not increasing.

Comment: @Wintermute by increasing if I mean not strictly?

Comment: What does "increasing at $c$" mean?

Comment: @user251257 It means that there is an interval $(a',b')\subset[a,b]$ such that $c\in(a,b)$, and that$$(\forall x\in(a',b')):x<c\implies f(x)<f(c)\wedge x>c\implies f(x)>f(c).$$

Comment: $(1)$ is wrong, consider $x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} + \frac{x}{2}$ with $f(0) = 0$ defined on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @user251257 that there is a left nbd of c where $f(x)$ is strictly less than $f(c)$ and a right nbd where $f(x)$ is strictly greater than $f(c)$

Comment: @HritRoy With your definition, it's true, because if $f'(c) > 0$ the difference quotient $\frac{f(c) - f(x)}{c-x}$ is also positive in a neighbourhood of $c$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 that is indeed how I support my claim

Comment: @HritRoy There's alternative ways to define "increasing at a point". You can also define "increasing at $c$" as meaning "there is a neighbourhood of $c$ such that the restriction of $f$ to that neighbourhood is an increasing function". With that (stronger) definition, it's false.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 jose doesn't require monotonicity in an interval. It is the same as Hrit Roy's statement.

Comment: @user251257 Yes, likewise I edited my comment. Misread it.

Comment: I think my 2nd claim has something to do with that